# Download list of files loop - net/http

Tags: ruby, loops, download

```
 require 'net/http' 
 1.upto(99) do |novel|
    puts "Downloading ##{novel}..."
    Net::HTTP.start("http://www.nbc.com") do |http|
      resp = http.get("/heroes/novels/downloads/Heroes_novel_0#{novel}.pdf")
      open("Heroes_novel_#{novel}.pdf", "w") do |file|
        file.write(resp.body)
      end
    end
    puts "Next..."
    puts
 end
puts "Okay, Sneak it's done!"
```

When I run my script I get these errors:

> C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize':
>   getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (SocketError)
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in`open'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in`timeout'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in`connect'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in`start'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:490:in `start'
>           from heroes.rb:5:in`block in '
>           from heroes.rb:3:in `upto'
>           from heroes.rb:3:in`'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse the proper parameters into `start()`. It takes a host and a port. The easiest way to do this is to make a URI object first.

```
uri = URI('http://www.nbc.com')
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  #do some get requests and handle it
end
```

This translates to `Net::HTTP.start("www.nbc.com", 80)`